# Meanings in "Mon Maquis" by Alizée

Tags: meaning, pop

[well, written by Mylène Farmer, I believe]

So ... I love this song! I feel like it would fit well as an eve-of-battle song in the Lord of the Rings or something. Anyway, I would just like to know what messages are in the lyrics. A full translation would be greatly appreciated, but just a general interpretation would be fine.

I believe Maquis refers to French Resistance fighters, right? So, is it a historical ballad, or a metaphor for something else, or ...

Here's a video: [Mon Maquis live on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HTDp1MUwq0)

Comment: See [this translation](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/mon-maquis-my-scrubland.html)

Answer (score 1):

The French word "maquis" was possibly coined by Guy de Maupassant in his short story, A Vendetta in 1883:

> On the other side of the channel she watched from morning till night a white speck on the coast. It was a little Sardinian village, Longosardo, where Corsican bandits fled for refuge when too hard pressed. They formed almost the entire population of this hamlet, facing the shores of their own country, and there they awaited a suitable moment to come home, to return to the **"maquis"** of Corsica.

The quotation marks around the world "maquis" are in Maupassant's text, signifying invention. The origin of the French word is uncertain but is thought to be derived from the Italian *macchia*, meaning thicket or scrubland.

"Mon maquis" is a song from the album "Gourmandises" by Alizée. The album was released in France on November 21, 2000. The song was written by Mylène Farmer and composed by Laurent Boutonnat. Farmer has acted as  a mentor for Alizee's career.

Alizée, herself, was born in Ajaccio, Corsica, where Maupassant's story is set.

The lyrics of the song can be [translated into English](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/mon-maquis-my-scrubland.html) as:

> **My scrubland**
>   It's an inextricable maze,
>   and impenetrable too.
>   It's my scrub... my bed:
>   it's my scrubland
>   It is a shelter, a room without a view
>   where the air is pure, so pure,
>   my scrub... my bed is:
>   it's my scrubland.

The lyrics seem fairly straightforward enough and can be seen as someone who enjoys being in the comforting landscape of their childhood, lying out in the bushes.

Comment: "maquis" was also the name for the WW2 French Resistance fighers